# How to select a records by specific month / year

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the last missing piece in my website unfortunately I need to generate sales report as well. I don't know where to start.

How can i display the records from a specific week, month, year. and total the amount

TABLE:  payments.tbl

```
 payment_id amount  customer_id product_id  trx_id  currency    payment_date
 21     10470        1       15      5F110606611093636  PHP    2015-03-30
```

NOTE: payment_date structure is DATE

Comment: GROUP BY, combined with the aggregate function SUM.

Comment: can you give me example.. like for this month

Comment: Which dbms are yuo using? (I'm asking since date/time handling is too often not ANSI SQL compliant...)

Comment: or better can i get the records by inputting three textbox like. Year: Month: Day: and store them in variable so i can just select them

Answer (score 0):

You get specific records with `WHERE`.

You get a total amount with `SUM()`.

How to deal with dates depends on your DBMS, because different DBMS feature different date functions. Here is an example for MySQL:

```
select 
  sum(amount) as total_amount, 
  currency,
  count(distinct customer_id) as number_of_different_customers,
  count(distinct product_id) as number_of_different_products
from mytable
where month(payment_date) = month(curdate()) and year(payment_date) = year(curdate())
group by currency;
```

I group by currency here to get one result record per currency, as it makes no sense to sum amounts of different currencies.

Date functions for MySQL are found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html.